# realtime update value in form from table

Tags: jquery

I have created a table to calculate grand total of a few fields in real time .I have a form after the table with an input field named amount ,how can i make its value also get updated in real time to same value as the grand total in the table. Meaning if grand total in table is 10 then this value in form should also change to 10.

See  fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hSxkW/48/

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>VARIABLE</th>
               <th>QTY</th>
            <th>PRICE</th>
            <th>SUM</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Millage</td>
            <td><input class='qty' size='1'/></td>
            <td class='price'>1.25</td>
            <td class='sum'>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Number of vans</td>
            <td><input class='qty' size='1'/></td>
            <td class='price'>2.10</td>
            <td class='sum'>0</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>Total</td>
            <td id='total'></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<form action="">
<input name="amount" value="0.00">
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
function getTotal(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.sum').each(function(){
        total += parseFloat(this.innerHTML)
    });
    $('#total').text(total);
}

getTotal();

$('.qty').keyup(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('tr');
    var price = $('.price', parent);
    var sum = $('.sum', parent);
    var value = parseInt(this.value) * parseFloat(price.get(0).innerHTML||0);
    sum.text(value);
    getTotal();
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after you do

```
$('#total').text(total);
```

You can do

```
$("form input[name='amount']").val(total);
```

Comment: No its not correct.It does not show grand total but instead just total of a row

Comment: @user3583220: You will see that I updated the answer to use the `total` in the `getTotal()` method after I caught my initial mistake.

Comment: Yeah now it looks correct i will choose it as correct answer after 10 minutes.

Comment: Thank you. I apologize for the initial mix-up. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[name="amount"]').keyup(function() {
    total = parseFloat(0);
    $('.price').each(function() {
        total += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
    $('#total').text(total);
});
```

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for. "if grand total in table is 10 then this value in form should also change to 1" There should not be a need for a keyup event on the form field.

Answer (score -1):

You mean like this?

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>VARIABLE</th>
               <th>QTY</th>
            <th>PRICE</th>
            <th>SUM</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Millage</td>
            <td><input class='qty' size='1'/></td>
            <td class='price'>1.25</td>
            <td class='sum'>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Number of vans</td>
            <td><input class='qty' size='1'/></td>
            <td class='price'>2.10</td>
            <td class='sum'>0</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>Total</td>
            <td id='total'></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<form action="">
<input id="amount" name="amount" value="0.00"><!-- add an id for amount -->
</form>


function getTotal(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.sum').each(function(){
        total += parseFloat(this.innerHTML)
    });
    $('#total').text(total);
    $('#amount').val(total); // set 'amount' value.
    // $("form input[name='amount']").val(total); // If you want to target it by name, use this.
}

getTotal();

$('.qty').keyup(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('tr');
    var price = $('.price', parent);
    var sum = $('.sum', parent);
    var value = parseInt(this.value) * parseFloat(price.get(0).innerHTML||0);
    sum.text(value);
    getTotal();
})
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hSxkW/51/)

Comment: In this example, `$("#amount")` will not work as `amount` is the `name` not the `id`.

Comment: Yes, and you can see my example in jsfiddle, I added an id for amount.

Comment: is there a method to target it by name

Comment: Yes, as I put in my example `$("form input[name='amount']")`

Comment: Right, $("form input[name='amount']") can target it by name.